# What does $.query.get('code') mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

What does `$.query.get('code')` mean in jQuery?

Comment: Where did you see this line of code?

Comment: Maybe a jQuery plugin retrieving the value for the `code` parameter in the query string. It's impossible to answer that question without any further information.

Comment: Maybe it gets the value of 'code' from the query string.

Comment: I would like to see any other interpretation except ONE given. There should be MANY of them if question is really AMBIGUOUS :)

Comment: @Dims: Your question is vague, there is no definite answer, only assumptions. I could also say the code alerts `42`, see: `$.query = { get: function() { alert('42'); }};`. This should be searched on Google but not asked here.

Comment: @Felix, try to google this yourself before suggesting. Also I said that this is a qstn about jQuery. If only jQuery libraries are included and a computer can execute this, so how it can be ambiguous?

Comment: Because this piece of code could do *anything*, that's what I tried to tell you with my example. It's the same as asking *"What does `bar()` do in JavaScript?"*... it could be *anything*, so any answer is as good as the other.

Comment: Any non built-in function can do anything. For example printf() in C. So no one can ask about it here, right? I mentioned (1) function and (2) library, and this was enough for those who knew. And people answered this, while google didn't due to special characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`$.query`](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) is a jQuery plugin to read the query string on a url (the `$_GET` variables).

```
$.query.get('code')
```

This gets the value of `code` if the url was something like `http://example.com?code=123`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [jQuery query string object plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) that is retrieving "code" from the query string (GET variable).

For example running on the page: "page.php?code=true" would return "true"